# React Native generate thumbnail for video url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, react-native

I have videos that I'd like to present as thumbnails before a user clicks on them for the full video. They are not local, I only have the url. Is there a RN component to do this? The RN Image component does not take videos urls as sources.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I can't figure out a way to get the actual video file.

Comment: I haven't come across anything yet @Keng

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible. Video thumbnail cannot be auto-generated from video URL. It should be created and stored along with the video in backend database and when RN app receives video URL, it should receive thumbnail URL too. Then you can use `Image` and `TouchableOpacity` components to add pressing behavior on the thumbnail.

However, if you use Youtube videos only, then [react-native-thumbnail-video](https://github.com/lucasbento/react-native-thumbnail-video) might be a quick solution to your problem.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible using [Expo Video Thumbnail library](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video-thumbnails/)

just like this example

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button, View, Image, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as VideoThumbnails from 'expo-video-thumbnails';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    image: null,
  };

  generateThumbnail = async () => {
    try {
      const { uri } = await VideoThumbnails.getThumbnailAsync(
        'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        {
          time: 15000,
        }
      );
      this.setState({ image: uri });
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(e);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { image } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button onPress={this.generateThumbnail} title="Generate thumbnail" />
        {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
        <Text>{image}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});
```

-UPDATE-

another way to do this is using video library without playing the video and the controllers

example:

```
npm install --save react-native-video



import Video from 'react-native-video';

// Within your render function, assuming you have a file called
// "background.mp4" in your project. You can include multiple videos
// on a single screen if you like.

<Video source={{uri: "background"}}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
       paused={true}
controls={false}
/>
```

in this example, it will display the video without playing it, so basically will give you the thumbnail.

**P.S: Not recommended if you have multiple videos in the same view more than 10.**

Comment: But it's not working for local video files. Do you have any idea? @Balalen

Comment: another way to do it is, load the vide player without playing it, this way it will display the Thumbnail without playing the video, i edited the answer, take a look

Comment: Other day I forgot to respond here. Actually expo-video-thumbnails works for local video file as well. I had some coding issue in my local, that's it didn't work. But when I cross checked, it was working fine. thanks for the reply @Balalen

Comment: @Balalen expo-video-thumbnails works fine for me, thanks!

Comment: I am getting error in IOS  [Error: Can't write to file.]

Comment: @Bhadresh which solution you are using ? the expo one or the video one ?

Comment: @Balalen see my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525358/error-cant-write-to-file-error-in-react-native-expo-video-thumbnails-ios

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no react-native component/api that does this. However, you can leverage native OS apis (`AVAssetImageGenerator` on ios and `MediaMetadataRetriever` on android) to generate thumbnails from video url in your react-native app.

For a quick solution, you can use [react-native-create-thumbnail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-create-thumbnail). It's a wrapper around the above mentioned system apis and supports both remote and local videos.

Answer (score 2):

It can be very easily done now using `expo-video-thumbnails`

Installation:

```
expo install expo-video-thumbnails
```

Example Code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button, View, Image, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as VideoThumbnails from 'expo-video-thumbnails';

export default function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const generateThumbnail = async () => {
    try {
      const { uri } = await VideoThumbnails.getThumbnailAsync(
        'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        {
          time: 15000,
        }
      );
      setImage(uri);
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button onPress={generateThumbnail} title="Generate thumbnail" />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={styles.image} />}
      <Text>{image}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Source:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/video-thumbnails/#videothumbnailsoptions

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following steps:

Step 1: Install the **"react-native-link-preview"** package on current project using this command:

```
yarn add react-native-link-preview
```

Step 2: This is the code where you can get link details: like link title, link thumbnail images, etc.

```
LinkPreview.getPreview('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MejbOFk7H6c')
        .then(data => console.debug(data));
```

Full Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';
import LinkPreview from 'react-native-link-preview';

let links = [
    {
        link: 'https://aws.amazon.com/'
    },
    {
        link: 'https://firebase.google.com/'
    },
    {
        link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kmiw4FYTg2U'
    },
    {
        link: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_Native'
    },
    {
        link:'https://stackoverflow.com/'
    }
];

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            linkData: []
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let _tempLinkData = [];
        for (let link of links) {
            await LinkPreview.getPreview(link.link)
                .then(data => {
                    console.debug("Data : ", data);
                    let _newLinkDetails = {
                        link: link.link,
                        title: data.title,
                        thumbnail: data.images[0]
                    };
                    _tempLinkData.push(_newLinkDetails);
                });

        }
        this.setState({ linkData: _tempLinkData });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ marginTop: 35 }}>
                <FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 20}}
                    data={this.state.linkData}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", padding: 5 }}>
                            <Image
                                style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
                                source={{ uri: item.thumbnail }}
                            />
                            <View style={{ marginLeft: 10, }}>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, lineHeight: 20, }}>{item.title}</Text>
                                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between", }}>
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, lineHeight: 20, color: "#a1a1a1" }}>{item.link}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    )}

                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
                />
            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this package [React Native Create Thumbnail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-create-thumbnail) to create thumbnail from the video URL. Read the documentation it's so easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "react-native-compressor" package to get thumbnail from video url

import function from package:

```
import {createVideoThumbnail} from 'react-native-compressor'
```

create thumbnail and set it to constant

```
const thumbnail = await createVideoThumbnail(videoFileUrl);
```

Comment: Very good !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For Android only:

Turns out you can just use `<Image />` or `<FastImage />` and pass the video source, you just can't choose the specific time/frame to use for the thumbnail. Way less hassle tbh.

Source: https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/issues/700

Using Expo's `VideoThumbnail` package was a nightmare, and always ended up crashing the app when trying to call `generateThumbnail()` on null...

Answer (score 0):

**Its possible to use Following code**

```
<ImageBackground>
       <View style={{alignItems:'center',marginTop:'50%'}}>
                 <Icon name='caret-forward-circle-outline' size={50} color={'#000'}/>
       </View>
</ImageBackground>
```

-**Note**
i think its not Work in IOS but its possible in android

Comment: <Icon> : import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Im using react-native-ffmpeg to export thumnails:

> ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:14.435 -frames:v 1 out.png

See this [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)