# How to create Thumbnail from mp4 in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I get a problem to create thumbnail from mp4 in react native, I have tried, but all examples fail, and the last I try to use this plugin https://github.com/lucasbento/react-native-thumbnail-video, if use youtube url is success, but when use mp4 url cannot show the thumbnail, you can use this mp4 url to testing https://filev4.subiz.com/fiqbjssxydufxauruqxi-video_test.mp4.

This is my result, cannot show the thumbnail.

[image]

Please anyone help me to solve this problem, Thanks.

Comment: Tried this library ? "https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native generate thumbnail for video url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905141/react-native-generate-thumbnail-for-video-url)

Answer (score 1):

For creating thumbnails for mp4 files you need utility on the server like ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a thumbnail of a .mp4 video using [react-native-thumbnail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-thumbnail) npm package. Here is an example of thumbnail creation using react-native-thumbnail package:

```
import RNThumbnail from 'react-native-thumbnail';

getThumbnail = async (uri) => { // uri is the local path of the video
    try {
        RNThumbnail.get(uri).then((result) => {
           console.log("Thumbnail path: " + result.path); // thumbnail path
           this.setState({ thumbUri: result.path });
        });
      }
    } catch (exp) {
      console.log(exp);
    }
}
```