# Error: Can't write to file error in react native expo-video-thumbnails IOS

Tags: react-native

I am generating a thumbnail from the video URL, it's working in android fine but in IOS getting the error `(Error: Can't write to file)`

Here below is my code.

```js
import * as VideoThumbnails from 'expo-video-thumbnails';

var thumbnail = await VideoThumbnails.getThumbnailAsync(link, { time: 2000 });
```

Comment: Do you have permission to write ?

Comment: no still I don't have

Comment: You need to ask the phone for permission to access the gallery